# XRay for Jira - Equivalent of Scenario Outlines

Tags: jira

I am trying to translate cucumber into XRay for Jira issues with the right structure. The result should be issues with Test Executions I can run for every example.

I want to make a test with multiple 'Examples' a-la Scenario Outlines in Cucumber.

Am I wanting to do Test Sets? A Test Plan?

Something else? I need an XRay for Cucumber testers intro.

Example fake Scenario Outline.

```
Scenario Outline: Ensure privs restricted
  Given I am logged onto "<container>"
  And I run the priv check
  Then privs are restricted
Examples:
| container |
| rabbit1   |
| zalenium1 |
| zalenium2 |
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems XRay fully supports Gherkin and scenario outlines, did you try the documentation?

- How to Create a Cucumber Test with Xray: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbOGhtof4WY
- Xray Documentation Home  Automation
  Direct naar einde van de banner
  Ga naar begin van de banner
  Testing in BDD with Gherkin based frameworks (e.g. Cucumber): https://confluence.xpand-it.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=46858243

Answer (score 0):

To achieve equivalent functionality of Scenario Outlines in XRay for Jira, you can use Test Sets. Test Sets allow you to create multiple tests with varying data inputs, similar to the 'Examples' in a Scenario Outline.

Steps to create Test Set:

1. Create a Test Issue in Jira
2. In the XRay Test tab, select "Add Test Set"
3. Enter a name for the Test Set and add a description (optional)
4. Define the parameters for the Test Set (e.g. container in your example)
5. Add Test Cases to the Test Set, each with its own set of parameter values
6. Save and Close the Test Set

When you run the Test Set, XRay will automatically create individual Test Executions for each set of parameter values, allowing you to test each scenario defined in your 'Examples' table.

Here are some resources you can use to learn about XRay for Jira:

1. XRay for Jira official documentation: https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/XRAY/Xray+Documentation
2. XRay for Jira - How to get started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_KjfFGk-Xc
3. XRay for Jira - User Guide: https://docs.getxray.app/docs/user-guide
4. XRay for Jira - Advanced Topics: https://docs.getxray.app/docs/advanced-topics

These resources should provide a good starting point to learn about XRay for Jira and its features.